# New - Google Play Store DEFAULT update popup

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, auto-update

I am seeing a default google play popup (by Google Play itself) in various apps. Is there any new integration from Google Play. Is it publicly available or being rolled out by google play to selected developers.

It allows the users to download the application with the application open and it installs the new version with the new app open session.

Screenshots are attached below:
[image: Installing]
[image: Update Paytm]

Comment: [Implement an in-app update function](https://medium.com/grandcentrix/implement-an-in-app-updater-1f50fbc38416)

Comment: Google Play [has recently announced](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/11/07/app-updates-api-will-let-android-apps-update-use/) they are going to offer an in-app update function. This isn't available for all developers yet, but should be soon. Watch out for the announcement.

Comment: Anyone knows how can this be blocked? It is really annoying!

Comment: Can I able to customize the screen as per the above? I am not seeing any doc